# Driver error when using multiple shaders

Tags: c++, shader, directx-11

I'm using 3 different shaders:

- a tessellation shader to use the tessellation feature of DirectX11 :)
- a regular shader to show how it would look without tessellation
- and a text shader to display debug-info such as FPS, model count etc.

All of these shaders are initialized at the beginning.

Using the keyboard, I can switch between the tessellation shader and regular shader to render the scene. Additionally, I also want to be able toggle the display of debug-info using the text shader.

Since implementing the tessellation shader the text shader doesn't work anymore. When I activate the DebugText (rendered using the text-shader) my screens go black for a while, and Windows displays the following message:

> Display Driver stopped responding and has recovered

[image: Display driver stopped]

This happens with either of the two shaders used to render the scene.

Additionally:
I can start the application using the regular shader to render the scene and then switch to the tessellation shader. If I try to switch back to the regular shader I get the same error as with the text shader.

What am I doing wrong when switching between shaders?
What am I doing wrong when displaying text at the same time?

What file can I post to help you help me? :) thx

P.S. I already checked if my keyinputs interrupt at the wrong time (during render or so..), but that seems to be ok

### Testing Procedure

1. Regular Shader without text shader
   [image: Regular Shader]
2. Add text shader to Regular Shader by keyinput (works now, I built the text shader back to only vertex and pixel shader) (somthing with the z buffer is stil wrong...)
   [image: Regular Shader and Font Shader]
3. Remove text shader, then change shader to Tessellation Shader by key input
   [image: Tessellation Shader without Font Shader]
4. Then if I add the Text Shader or switch back to the Regular Shader
   [image: Display driver stopped]

### Switching/Render Shader

Here the code snipet from the Renderer.cpp where I choose the Shader according to the boolean "m_useTessellationShader":

```
if(m_useTessellationShader) 
{
    // Render the model using the tesselation shader
    ecResult = m_ShaderManager->renderTessellationShader(m_D3D->getDeviceContext(), meshes[lod_level]->getIndexCount(), 
        worldMatrix, viewMatrix, projectionMatrix, textures, texturecount, 
        m_Light->getDirection(), m_Light->getAmbientColor(), m_Light->getDiffuseColor(), 
        (D3DXVECTOR3)m_Camera->getPosition(), TESSELLATION_AMOUNT);
} else { 
    // todo: loaded model depends on distance to camera
    // Render the model using the light shader.
    ecResult = m_ShaderManager->renderShader(m_D3D->getDeviceContext(), 
        meshes[lod_level]->getIndexCount(), lod_level, textures, texturecount,
        m_Light->getDirection(), m_Light->getAmbientColor(), m_Light->getDiffuseColor(),
        worldMatrix, viewMatrix, projectionMatrix);
}
```

And here the code snipet from the Mesh.cpp where I choose the Typology according to the boolean "useTessellationShader":

```
// RenderBuffers is called from the Render function. The purpose of this function is to set the vertex buffer and index buffer as active on the input assembler in the GPU. Once the GPU has an active vertex buffer it can then use the shader to render that buffer.
void Mesh::renderBuffers(ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext, bool useTessellationShader)
{
    unsigned int stride;
    unsigned int offset;

    // Set vertex buffer stride and offset.
    stride = sizeof(VertexType); 
    offset = 0;

    // Set the vertex buffer to active in the input assembler so it can be rendered.
    deviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &m_vertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);

    // Set the index buffer to active in the input assembler so it can be rendered.
    deviceContext->IASetIndexBuffer(m_indexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);

    // Check which Shader is used to set the appropriate Topology
    // Set the type of primitive that should be rendered from this vertex buffer, in this case triangles.
    if(useTessellationShader)
    {       
        deviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_3_CONTROL_POINT_PATCHLIST);
    }else{
        deviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
    }

    return;
}
```

### RenderShader

Could there be a problem using sometimes only vertex and pixel shader and after switching using vertex, hull, domain and pixel shader?
Here a little overview of my architecture:

- TextClass: uses font.vs and font.ps

  deviceContext->VSSetShader(m_vertexShader, NULL, 0); 
  deviceContext->PSSetShader(m_pixelShader, NULL, 0); 
  deviceContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &m_sampleState);
- RegularShader: uses vertex.vs and pixel.ps

  deviceContext->VSSetShader(m_vertexShader, NULL, 0); 
  deviceContext->PSSetShader(m_pixelShader, NULL, 0); 
  deviceContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &m_sampleState);
- TessellationShader: uses tessellation.vs, tessellation.hs, tessellation.ds, tessellation.ps

  deviceContext->VSSetShader(m_vertexShader, NULL, 0); 
  deviceContext->HSSetShader(m_hullShader, NULL, 0); 
  deviceContext->DSSetShader(m_domainShader, NULL, 0); 
  deviceContext->PSSetShader(m_pixelShader, NULL, 0); 
  deviceContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &m_sampleState);

### ClearState

I'd like to switch between 2 shaders and it seems they have different context parameters, right? In [clearstate methode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it says it resets following params to NULL:

I found following in my Direct3D Class:

- depth-stencil state -> m_deviceContext->OMSetDepthStencilState
- rasterizer state -> m_deviceContext->RSSetState(m_rasterState);
- blend state -> m_device->CreateBlendState
- viewports -> m_deviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

I found following in every Shader Class:

- input/output resource slots -> deviceContext->PSSetShaderResources
- shaders -> deviceContext->VSSetShader to - deviceContext->PSSetShader
- input layouts -> device->CreateInputLayout
- sampler state -> device->CreateSamplerState

These two I didn't understand, where can I find them?

- predications -> ?
- scissor rectangles -> ?

Do I need to store them all localy so I can switch between them, because it doesn't feel right to reinitialize the Direct3d and the Shaders by every switch (key input)?!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if the device is being reset by the system. Check the return variable of the Present() Method. When switching shaders abruptly DX tends to reset the device for some odd reason.

If this is the problem, just recreate the device and context and you should be good.

Comment: I just updated my post. on [gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/52853/driver-error-when-using-multiple-shaders) they succested to use [ID3D11DeviceContext::ClearState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476389.aspx) but I'm not really sure how to switch the d3d efficiently without reinitialize every switch.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do it every switch. When I was running into this issue, I noticed the device being reinitialized only once in a while. ClearState() works I guess, but I never used it really. Instead of clearing the device get the return value from the Present() method and only reset your device when necessary, i.e. when it returns DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_RESET or DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED . [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174576(v=vs.85).aspx)**msdn**

Comment: Also try going back on driver version, you might have discovered a driver bug. I just remember I went back one driver version and that fixed the problem. I waited until the next driver came out and the problem was gone permanently. PS. You game is looking good brother, even though you are getting some low frames.

Comment: I tried to reset the driver, but I recognized I had the 12.10 version of catalyst, so I updated to the newer 13.1. But still the same error.
Thx for the link! :) I tried to put the present somewhere but somehow it didn;t worked. In my Direct3D class I always request the HRESULT, but I just have the initialize function, how can I get the present in the renderer::frame function to see the HRSULT? Maybe you would like to look inside the project? [projectDX11](http://jinxi.ch/diverses/jinxi-wa-tessellation.rar) thx for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Right now you have

```
void Direct3D::endScene()
{
    // Present the back buffer to the screen since rendering is complete.
    if(m_vsync_enabled)
    {
        // Lock to screen refresh rate.
        m_swapChain->Present(1, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        // Present as fast as possible.
        m_swapChain->Present(0, 0);
    }

    return;
}
```

I would suggest doing something like so to catch the return value of Present()

```
ULONG Direct3D::endScene()
{
  int synch = 0;

  if(m_vsync_enabled)
    synch = 1;

  // Present as fast as possible or synch it to 1 vertical blank
  return m_swapChain->Present(synch, 0);
}
```

Of course this is only MY way of doing it, and there are many. Also, I forgot to tell you that the issue I had in the past was also using the Effects library. Have you recompiled it in your system? If not, then do so. Or even better get rid of it, that's what I did when I solved my problem.

Comment: many thanks for that, I already forgot that I used it... I'm pretty new to this Direct3D stuff :) When I try your code it also crashes at the `return m_swapChain->Present(synch, 0);`, but it never sets `m_vsync_enabled` to true, when do I need to set `m_vsync_enabled` to true? But even when I set `return m_swapChain->Present(1, 0);` it crashes at that line.
By effects library you meen `swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;`? I commented out but didn't make any difference even after rebuilding. If I try this project on a NVIDIA card it doesn;t crash  but shows only black.

Comment: The effects library is the actual Effects.lib that you are using to compile your shaders. There are a couple of things that can improve your code and overall performance of your program. I know you are new to DX, so I would suggest to start fixing them as you go. I will definitely start by getting rid of the effects library and D3DXMath which are both obsolete. PS. The code that you sent me did not contain the shaders so I couldn't compile it and see if it did the same thing in my system.

Comment: hmmm... I forgot to add the font shader I assume... I uploaded a newer version, but I;m using VS2012 now, just incase you get strange errors. I also tried some things with the `deviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers` but I dont really understand what this is. I know my code isn;t as pretty as I'd like to ;) but I improved some stuff maybe it is getting better. do you mean this `D3DX11CompileFromFile(...)` by I'm compiling the shader with effects.lib? What are you using instead of the D3DXMath?

Comment: if it compiles! under Tessellation/Resources/keyboardShortcut.txt you can find the keyboard/mouse input. additionally with 4 you can toggle wireframe and solid!
If the project is running, hit 3 for the text. then hit 3 (text) to remove text. then hit 2 to change to use the tessellationshader. If you hit 3(text) then, it crushes with my AMD Graphics card. with nVidia GC you might get a black screen!